# Get the type of the iterator using `decltype`

Tags: c++, decltype

I want to get the type of the iterator on objects of (template)type `A` using

```
typedef decltype(A::begin) A_iterator;
```

However, this gives a

> "*cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::begin" is intended*"

when `A` is a `std::vector<...>`.

I think the compiler cannot distinguish between the `const` function `begin` and the non-`const` function `begin`. How can I choose between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `A` is a type, and not a variable identifier.

```
using A_iterator = decltype(std::declval<A>().begin());
```

Or just...

```
using A_iterator = typename A::iterator;
```

If `A` is a variable identifier:

```
using A_iterator = decltype(A.begin());
```

Comment: Similarly `std::declval<const A>().begin()` and `typename A::const_iterator`